# Easiest way to format text bullets in textview on Android

Tags: android, formatting, textview

I looked around but did not find anything suitabe to just format text like this on Android textview.

- text that is in one line
- text that is longer and will

  continue on next line with 
  automatic indentation
- and so on...

That's it already. Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't believe such functionality exists. I suppose the idea would be to start by subclassing TextView and somehow take the text and add the bulleting programmaticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there are no really good typographic features in Android -- no full justification, bullets, leading, etc. -- so one thing I've seen suggested for this is to simply use a WebView, and then just insert the proper HTML, e.g.:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I do not know if direct HTML does hanging indents like you're asking, but there's probably a CSS property you could use that Android's WebView will support.

Answer (score 1):

You can format `TextView` like you do for a HTML page using `Html.fromHtml`. Check below snippet for more details...

```
String test1 = "<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>";
Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(test1);
tv.setText(s);
```

However, `TextView` doesn't support all HTML Tags. Check below Mark Murply's commonsware link for supported tags by TextView.

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Thanks for the very good hint. But for some reason I don't get <ul><li>item </li></ul>to work at all. The simple <br> is ok....

Comment: Just noticied that tags ul and li are not supported by TextView. Check the link I posted for supported Tags. </p> For tag "a" is used to highligght a text as link for that you have to call "tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());"

Comment: This doesn't work if you have one line that wraps then the second line of text justifies to the bullet